# FooterSummary Column Is calculating sum of the current page in jqgrid

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

Hii Guys!!
               I added footerrow in jqgrid to display summary of the column but it is calculating sum of only the current page and displaying into the footer row..
I have added filter toolbar in jqgrid to filter records .According to my need i want total sum 
of particular column from whole grid And it should work when we filter the record and summary should come of the current data present in the whole grid for particular column...

Here is my code to calculate summary ....

```
$(function () {
var gridData = null;
var nn = null;
$.ajax({
    url: 'Default.aspx/MyMethod',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (ReportDataNew, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        //debugger;
        gridData = JSON.parse(ReportDataNew.d);
        console.log(gridData);
        //alert(gridData.length);

        grid = $("#gridId"),
            calculateTotal = function () {
                var totalAmount = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'price', false, 'sum');
                grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { name: 'TOTAL', price: totalAmount });
            };
```

And here I am populating my grid ...

```
 $("#gridId").jqGrid({
            data: gridData,
            datatype: "local",
            height: '100%',
            autowidth: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 200, 300],
            colNames: ['UserName', 'Ordinal', 'Extension', 'Trunk', 'Dialnumber', 'DialDate', 'DialTime', 'Duration', 'Destination', 'Price'],
            colModel: [
                       { name: 'username', index: 'username', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                       { name: 'price', index: 'price', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center'}

                      ],
            pager: '#gridpager',
            viewrecords: true,
            toppager: true,
            loadtext: 'Loading...',
            footerrow: true,
            userDataOnFooter: true,
            gridComplete: function () {
                calculateTotal();
            }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are calculating the sum on the server side you are probably doing it on the paged results. Expand the calculation to include the whole record set not just the portion that is being passed to the jqGrid in the current page it is displaying.

Comment: Sir I am using local data to calculate sum .code is in my post...Plz see